# how to get rid of this linking error?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, linker, linker-errors

I am trying to compile some files and it is just fine but when I try to link them as follow I get an error :

```
Building target: EoCu
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L"/home/workspace/production-Alginterface/Shared/libs" -m32 -g -rdynamic  -Wl,-rpath-link=../../production-Alginterface/Shared/libs -g -rdynamic -o "EoCu"  ./simpleini/ConvertUTF.o ./simpleini/snippets.o  ./Tinyxpath/action_store.o ./Tinyxpath/htmlutil.o ./Tinyxpath/lex_util.o ./Tinyxpath/node_set.o ./Tinyxpath/tinystr.o ./Tinyxpath/tinyxml.o ./Tinyxpath/tinyxmlerror.o ./Tinyxpath/tinyxmlparser.o ./Tinyxpath/tokenlist.o ./Tinyxpath/xml_util.o ./Tinyxpath/xpath_expression.o ./Tinyxpath/xpath_processor.o ./Tinyxpath/xpath_stack.o ./Tinyxpath/xpath_static.o ./Tinyxpath/xpath_stream.o ./Tinyxpath/xpath_syntax.o  ./AlarmsMsg.o ./AppWatchDog.o ./BaseIteration.o ./CommunicationManager.o ./ConfigValidator.o ./FilesMng.o ./GuiInputHandler.o ./GuiManager.o ./IniReader.o ./IniWriter.o ./MessageBuilder.o ./MngFile.o ./MsgBroker.o ./NetworkDisconnectTimerCallable.o ./ShareDialog.o ./SpoIteration.o ./TCPServer.o ./Timer.o ./TimerCallable.o ./TrendsRecorder.o ./TrendsUtlFunc.o ./XMLBuilder.o ./XMLParser.o ./actmgr.o ./cdlCom.o ./entry.o ./ioctrl.o ./iteration.o ./msgqueue.o ./prmdb.o ./qthread.o ./usbDrive.o   -lrt -llog4cxx -lapr-1 -laprutil-1 -lexpat -lpthread
```

I have entered the correct libraries when I compile and run via eclipse it works perfect, but when I do that via the make file I get this error although it is the same make files!, can any one help me with that?

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libexpat.so.0, needed by /home/workspace/production-Alginterface/Shared/libs/libaprutil-1.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What in warning you do not understand? It cannot find libexpat.so.0 so check and update your rpath accordingly

Comment: but it is under : "/home/workspace/production-Alginterface/Shared/libs"

Comment: Is libexpat.so.0 in that location 32 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely eclipse is using a different working directory so your `rpath-link` has a different meaning:

```
-Wl,-rpath-link=../../production-Alginterface/Shared/libs
                ^^^^^^
```

Try using an absolute path instead.

---

Why do you need to do this if you already specified `-L` on gcc's command line? From `ld(1)` I am guessing a separate path is searched for shared libraries required by other shared libraries of yours.

In this case you require `libaprutil-1.so` because you link with `-laprutil-1`. It is libaprutil that wants `libexpat.so.0` and `rpath-link` is the path searched by `ld`.

Comment: but when I link I did this :-L"/home/workspace/production-Alginterface/Shared/libs" which tells the linker where is the absolute path of all libs needed!!

Comment: where can I change the -rpath-link?!

Comment: @flashdisk Just to see if this works: the code you posted in your question has a "rpath-link". Try changing that.

Comment: ah ok, I will change that and try again and see if this is working!

Comment: @flashdisk What makes me think this could be needed is the fact that `libaprutil-1.so` wants this library so indeed ld's `rpath-link` is what you want to set, not `-L`.

Comment: but is that right that -L tells the linker to search for libs in this path?! why is the rpath-link needed?!

Comment: @flashdisk Glad it worked. I updated the answer to try to explain why you need this in addition to `-L`.